# computed field value in xpages

Tags: lotus-notes, xpages, lotus-domino

I am trying to update a computed fields value on click of a button with a value of a edit box + its own value.

Code written on button: here i put value of edit box in scope variable and make edit box blank. comment_te is the name of edit box

```
requestScope.put("commentValue", getComponent("comments_te").getValue);
getComponent("comments_te").setValue("");
```

Code written for value of computed field: comments is the name of computed field

```
getComponent("comments").getValue + "\n" + requestScope.get("commentValue")
```

But I get the output is:
0 com.ibm.xsp.component.xp.XspInputText@65426542

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're missing the parentheses in your calls to getValue(). By omitting these, you're returning a pointer to the getValue method of the component, not the result of invoking that method. Change each reference to getValue to getValue(), and you'll get a different result.

Answer (score 0):

Your code returning the Object.
Try the following.
This following code get the the editbox value and set to a scope variable.

```
requestScope.commentValue = getComponent("comments_te").value;
getComponent("comments_te").value = "";
```

This following code sets the value to the computed field.

```
getComponent("comments").value = getComponent("comments").value + "\n" + requestScope.commentValue;
```

When you are appending the value to the computed field, as default it will add 0 to its value. Do the validation if you want.

I hope this helps you...!!!